# Why are the elements for a non-relevant section template missing?

Tags: orbeon

I'm using a section template created by Orbeon Form Builder that I included in another form also created by Form Builder. When in this form we make the section template invisible, it disappears from the form instance.

Is it possible to make the section template invisible without loosing it in form instance?

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me; I will try to reproduce and investigate this tomorrow, and post a follow-up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each section templates, Form Builder generates an XBL component which wraps the fields in that section. In the form that uses the XBL corresponding to the section template, in the XML for the instance, there is just one element for the whole section, and the XBL component is bound to that element. The XBL component "knows" what the XML for the fields in the section is, and at runtime, when it becomes relevant, it inserts them inside the element for the section. Hence, if the section never becomes relevant, those fields will be missing from the instance.

This behavior isn't consistent with what happens for regular sections, but it shouldn't cause any particular problem to Form Runner. Say, if you save the data without those fields, edit it later, and the section becomes relevant, the XBL component will then add the elements to the instance. For this reason, we created this [issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/43).

Comment: After several tests, i just found that there's no problem when the section is visible on form load then hided on runtime. The problem occurs only when the section is invisible on form load

Comment: Exactly: the first time the section becomes relevant, the elements are added to the instance. So if the section is relevant when the form is loaded, then the elements will be there in the instance.

Comment: Is it planned that hided (or un-relevant) elements are added to the instance, too? Because as a user, I would expect this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I dont work on Form Builder, but you can make section/fields invisible using

1. `<xforms:group>` or
2. by using `relevant` condition in bind definition.

**If you use `<xforms:group>` then the section/fields will not be removed from model instance.**

If you use relevant condition, then the section will be removed from model instance when the relevant condition is false.

Comment: I confirm what you've said about using relevant. So i tried wraping the component from section template in an xforms:group like this <xforms:group ref=".[condition]"> <fr:section> <component:myComponent /> </fr:section> </xforms:group> but it worked the same as if i use relevant condition